# How to increase cell character limit PHPExcel TYPE LIST

Tags: php, phpexcel

Using PHPExcel to create a dropdown list like so:

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A".$i)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( \PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( \PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$formulaString = '"' .  implode(", ", $items_array) . '"';
$objValidation->setFormula1($formulaString);

$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$filename = "MyExcel.xlsx";
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The problem is it cuts off at `1023` characters hence breaking the "dropdown" function.

How do I increase the character limit?

Comment: Have you checked whether this is a limit imposed by PHPExcel or if it is a limit imposed by the format and/or Microsoft Excel?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I've updated the post with code where I create the file, I have a feeling its to do with the headers.

Comment: Trying it out with Excel 2007 itself, it seems it's not possible to type more than 256 characters. Have you thought about using a different sheet and using a cell range for your cell validation?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I think I will need to do that , can you point me in to the right resource/documentation that can show me how to do that?

Comment: I don't have the library installed anywhere, but what about using something like `$objvalidation->setFormula1('=MyOtherSheet!A:A');` for instance (if the acceptable values were all in column `A` on `MyOtherSheet`).

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thanks - I did that and it worked. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there is a limit to the length of a static list in data validation.

You should put the validation data in a range in the workbook somewhere and provide this range for the validation:

```
// Get options from another sheet
$objvalidation->setFormula1('ExampleSheet!A1:A100');
```

Comment: it is worked for you ? where did you put this line ? ExampleSheet is  sheet name or main name ?

Comment: i added like this `$cat_code->setFormula1('"'.$item_codes.'"');
        $cat_code->setFormula1('Item Prices!B1:B100');` but it wont work